# Error loading %s variable when executing cursor pymysql

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

I am trying to create a raspberry pi program that uploads the current temperature to a MySQL DB. I am currently stuck on this one line not working though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
sql="SELECT date FROM data.temperature WHERE date= %s"

val=(date)

cur.execute(sql, val)
```

This returns the error:

```
You have an error in your sql syntax near '%s' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `val=(date)` to `val=(date, )`. The second argument to cur.execute expects a tuple or list or dict. However, `val=(date)` doesn't create a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `%` is special characters in `MySQL`,you can use `\` to escape it

```
sql="SELECT date FROM data.temperature WHERE date= \%s"
```